# How Test Location Change in Genny motion

Tags: android, genymotion

How Test Location change from One position To another  In genny motion
 Here I posted My code Where On `onLocationChanged` never called

```
public class RouteMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
   LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback, 

GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener 


{

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;

private static final int LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60 * 2;

private static final LatLng latlngHiLiteMall = new LatLng(11.248823, 75.833760);

private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;


private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000;

private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; /


private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; 



boolean isGPSTrackingEnabled = false;
LatLng latLngMyLocation = null;
AlertDialog alertDlg;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder;
double myLocLat, myLocLong;
LocationManager locationManager;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo;
private Location mLastLocation;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_map);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(this);

    Log.e("Rout Map.....","on Create....!");

    if (checkPlayServices()) {

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        createLocationRequest();

    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

private void createLocationRequest() {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);

    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil

            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {

            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,

                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)

            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)

            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)

            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    checkPlayServices();

    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnabled)

        showAlertDialog();

    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

    stopLocationUpdates();
}

private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {

    if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {

        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

        startLocationUpdates();

        Log.d("TAG", "Periodic location updates started!");

    } else {


        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

        stopLocationUpdates();

        Log.d("TAG", "Periodic location updates stopped!");
    }
}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap != null) {

        return;
    }
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if (mMap == null) {

        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {

            if (!isGPSEnabled) {

                Toast.makeText(RouteMapActivity.this, "GPS is disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlngHiLiteMall).title("HiLite Mall"));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlngHiLiteMall, 12));


    //getMyCurrentLocation();
    getMyLocation();

}

private void getMyLocation() {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(googleApiClient);


    if (mLastLocation != null) {

        Log.d("NOT NULL", ">>>>>>>>>>>");

        if (alertDlg != null && alertDlg.isShowing())

            alertDlg.dismiss();

        myLocLat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();

        myLocLong = mLastLocation.getLongitude();


        if (connectionInfo.isConnectingToInternet()) {

            latLngMyLocation = new LatLng(myLocLat, myLocLong);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLngMyLocation).title("My Loc"));

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLngMyLocation, 12));

            new MapTask().execute();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Enable Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Toast.makeText(RouteMapActivity.this, "G--" + myLocLat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(RouteMapActivity.this, "Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



private Location getLastKnownLocation() {


    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);

    Location bestLocation = null;

    for (String provider : providers) {

        Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        Log.d("last known location", "" + provider + " " + l);

        if (l == null) {

            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null
                || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy())
        {
            Log.d("last known location", "" + provider + " " + l);

            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }
    if (bestLocation == null) {

        return null;
    }

    return bestLocation;
}


private void showAlertDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("Use Location?");


    alertDialog.setMessage("Helps for find the route to HiLite Mall.");


    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);

            startActivityForResult(intent, LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDlg = alertDialog.create();

    alertDlg.show();

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE) {

        Log.d("TAG", "Activity Result");

        getMyLocation();

    }

}



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    getMyLocation();

    if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    Log.i("API CLIENT", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

    Log.i("API CLIENT", "Connection suspended");

    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.e("Location Changed.....","Location changed....!");

    mLastLocation = location;
    // Displaying the new location on UI
    getMyLocation();
}





private class MapTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, PolylineOptions> {

    @Override
    protected PolylineOptions doInBackground(Void... params) {

        GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();

        Document doc = md.getDocument(latLngMyLocation, latlngHiLiteMall, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);

        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);

        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);


        for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {

            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
        }
        return rectLine;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PolylineOptions rectLine) {

        mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {

        case android.R.id.home:

            this.finish();

            return true;



    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: any one who suggest valuable link

Comment: onLocationChanged will not be called in emulator as your device is not moving and location is not getting changed . Try running your app in real device

Comment: But in genny motion has option to set location   ... when i reset my location  onLocationChanged method did not called why?

Comment: Iam sorry to disturbing you

Comment: check it in real device and first confirm if it is working in that or not

Comment: @ Vivek Thank you  man  for your corporation

Comment: @ nibu   Good Question

Comment: @ saeed Thanks but still in trouble

Comment: Are you sure your `startLocationUpdates` method is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Emulator Control* of *DDMS* to change the location.[image]

Comment: using this control   can i  change the location   of genny motion device?

Comment: also  onLocationChanged never called please give me valuable solution